# JAR Manifest - field "D" containing weird hash

Tags: java, jar, manifest.mf

I opened jar application with archive manger and under `META-INF` there was file `MANIFEST.MF` containing:

```
Manifest-Version: 9.9
Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.9.6
Class-Path: app.jar
Created-By: 1.7.0_80-b15 (Oracle Corporation)
Main-Class: test.App

Name: test/App.class
D: MCwCFCc9lvmNijUSfZwkwYoySDWuoRjhAhQ9yKS8YH7hKVZ54dTihEwk3Q27sw==
```

I am wondering what is this hash. It looks like base64 encoded, but it isn't. I checked and after modyfing it, app is not working, so this might be some checksum of file. I was looking for field `D` in [jar documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jar/jar.html), but I was unable to find any mention about it. So what exactly it is and where I can read about it?

Comment: Looks like some kind of digest over App.class. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/intro.html contains proper examples, you will have to check the ant build script used to create that jar to determine why it is named "D" and what exactly it contains.

Comment: It's not signed jar because `jarsigner -verify app.jar` return `jar is unsigned. (signatures missing or not parsable) `. I can't check build scripts, because I have only builded application without source.

Comment: Why do you think it isn't base64? It seems to be base64 of a binary hash. Now has to the meaning of D, I have no idea, all examples I've seen specify `<name-of-hash>-Digest`, see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jar/jar.html But it seems to behave like a signed jar. Maybe the application itself uses its own version of jar signing?